# Looker- Connect Filter Across Data Sources Using Dimension from Only One Source

Tags: filtering, looker-studio, looker

I have two data sets with a common ID field. One table (t1) is unique at the ID level with aggregated metrics, while the other (t2) includes customer KPIs for each ID (many to one KPIs to ID). I am looking to create a dropdown filter with each KPI from t1 that updates t2 charts based on the IDs corresponding to the selected KPI/s.

I've tried to create a common field_id based on ID across each table but the filter won't update charts since KPI is not a part of t2. Pre-joining or blending won't work since metrics are duplicated across KPI and much double counting would be introduced. I've also tried creating another filter for ID and hiding it behind a chart so that when these automatically update based on KPI, then t2 charts would also update. This didn't work.

An alternative solution could to join the tables and average metrics across KPI, then sum them across other dimensions afterwards in the Looker UI (depending on other filters), but I don't know if this is possible.